# Configure SSL for two sites with the same IP in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, iis-7

I would like to know how could I configure two sites for use as `https`. The sites are placed in the same machine (the same IP).

For example:

[image]

I want an application inside `site1.com` to be SSL, and other application inside `site2.com` to be SSL also. My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible?
2. Do I need just one certificate or I need two certificates?
3. How can I configure the bindings to have this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes  this is possible. But the second site will be using another port instead of 443.
2. Yes and Yes, if you are using  this as a production server then you need valid     certificate from certificate authority, for each certificate there is unique url(the url of the site to be used) associated with it, hence it cant be used with any other site.
3. If you are doing for your own demo/development then you can create self signed    certificate.
4. Import the certificate, then right click -> `Edit  bindings -> choose ssl` with the certificate for your site.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing, this is technically possible but requires more up to date SSL implementation on the client side
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication
This is pretty much all modern supported browsers, with exception of any IE version on XP - that could be a big deal for some people

As far as configuring IIS, this article describes how to do that - only IIS8 on Win2012 supports SNI though:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability.

The general solution is to request secondary IP from your hoster, and assign each ssl site its own ip in bindings.